# Blocking hostname and subdomains in hosts file

Tags: networking, dns, hostname, hosts

I have recently started using `/etc/hosts` to block distracting websites. For specific domains that works nicely, but is there any way to match a domain and all of its subdomains?

So, this blocks twitter and pinterest:

```
127.0.0.1   twitter.com
127.0.0.1   www.pinterest.com
```

But this doesn't block any tumblr page, and since users can create custom ones, I can't manually specify all of them:

```
127.0.0.1   tumblr.com
```

Using `*.tumblr.com` didn't work either. Is there some solution using the hosts file?

If not, I would also be fine with a solution involving `iptables`.